# TypeError: 'MyClass.MyFunction is not a function' error message in ES6 / Node 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

I am facing a bug which I can replicate with the following piece of code in a node.js 4.0 application:

```
"use strict";

var Immutable = require("immutable");

class AspectType {
    constructor(htmlLabel) { this.hhtmlLabel = htmlLabel; }
    htmlLabel() { return this.hhtmlLabel; }
}

var AspectTypes = Immutable.OrderedMap()
    .set("C",new AspectType("xxx"))
    .set("D",new AspectType("yyy"))
    .set("E",new AspectType("zzz"));


for (var retr in AspectTypes.values()) {
    console.log(retr.htmlLabel());
}
```

I am getting the following error message, why?

```
TypeError: retr.htmlLabel is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (...\testt.js:17:22)
```

Comment: Why make the function name the same as the string argument you are passing in constructor? That's so confusing!

Comment: Your code does work in babel. Hmm. https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%0D%0Aclass%20AspectType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(htmlLabel)%20%7B%20this.hhtmlLabel%20%3D%20htmlLabel%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20htmlLabel()%20%7B%20return%20this.hhtmlLabel%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20x%20%3D%20new%20AspectType(%22xxx%22)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(x.htmlLabel())%3B%0D%0A

Comment: I am not using Babel and don't want to use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pfff...

```
for (var retr of AspectTypes.values()) {
```

not

```
for (var retr in AspectTypes.values()) {
```

Comment: @Willian Did you notice the difference between `of` and `in` which explains the source of the error?